# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: asp.net

First I explain the concept:

I have two system both system have static ip address.

Desktop application developed in vb.net and back end is sql server.

Webapplication is developed in asp.net and backend is sql server.

I run desktop application in system1.
Webapplication run in another system2.

When I send http request from system2 to system1 they response my request.
Sometimes the remote server not connected because port 80 is blocked. That time it display the error message "*No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it*".

My Request Coding Example:

```
    Dim uri1 As New Uri("http://xx.xxx.xx.xx/SysConnectionStatus/")
    If (uri1.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttp) Then
        Dim wrequest1 As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri1)
        wrequest1.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get
        Dim wresponse1 As HttpWebResponse = wrequest1.GetResponse()
        Dim reader1 As New StreamReader(wresponse1.GetResponseStream())
        Dim tmp2 As String = reader1.ReadToEnd()
        wresponse1.Close()
        Response.Write(tmp2)
    End If
```

Response for that request is

```
   ALIVE
```

### When I restart my system1 the port 80 is opened. After some request I send then it will be blocked.

I already check the following things

```
  1.Windows firewall is disabled.
  2.No antivirus is installed
  3.No virus found in both system.
```

So what is the problem? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using skype that can grab port 80 before IIS manages to get it, but IIS won't tell you there was a problem. To fix, just go into the advanced connection settings in skype and untick the port 80 box.

Comment: SKYPE Not installed in my system.

Comment: is anything else grabbing the port? try using somethinh lke netpeeker, it can tell you what programs are listening on what ports.

Comment: thanks for your reply.Just now I check the netpeeker software in my friend system it tell port 80 is used by avg antivirus.